# Is accounts namespace similar to domain namespace?

Tags: accounts, account-name

[EOSIO Dawn 4.0 Release log](https://medium.com/eosio/eosio-dawn-4-0-release-b25661a49ac2) says:

> Due to the potential high-value of certain names, we believe that the EOSIO system should offer a dynamic pricing model for account names. Furthermore, the ability to namespace accounts such as *.com can provide an extra layer of security for users and/or groups.

If holder `A` gets an account named `net`, is it true all account names which ends with `.net` will be restricted to holder `A`?

Comment: the link you've provided is the medium post announcing the release of Dawn 4.0, but you're actually asking about this post (which was published earlier to introduce dawn 4.0):
https://medium.com/eosio/introducing-eosio-dawn-4-0-f738c552879

Answer (score 1):

No.

the accounts:

`accountA.companyX.com`

`accountB.companyY.com`

can have different owners.

Comment: Please note the EOSIO v. 1.0 will not allow creation of account names with `.` in it. Only alphanumerics.